# How to call for button action, inside from another button action in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift3, ibaction

I have below `button action`

```
@IBAction func actionB(_ sender: UIButton) {
 print("something")
}
```

and I want to call above button action inside below button action.

```
@IBAction func actionC(_ sender: UIButton) {
 //call to above button action in here
}
```

how can I do that. hope your help with this

Comment: self.actionB(BUTTONB_OUTLET) . use this code in your actionC method

Comment: @IBAction func actionC(sender: AnyObject) {
        //call to above button action in here
        self.actionB(UIButton)
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to do it ...

```
@objc fileprivate func methodA(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("method A")
}

@objc fileprivate func methodB(_ sender: UIButton) {
    methodA(sender)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 @IBAction func actionC(sender: AnyObject) {
        //call to above button action in here
        actionB(sender: sender);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
actionB("")
```

if you want you can also do like this

```
actionB(sender)
```

or

`actionB(ButtonB)`

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to:

```
@IBAction func actionB(sender: AnyObject?) {
 print("something")
 actionC(nil)
}

@IBAction func actionC(sender: AnyObject?) {
 //call to above button action in here
}
```

Notice the optional mark after AnyObject.

or

```
@IBAction func actionB(sender: AnyObject) {
 print("something")
}

@IBAction func actionC(sender: AnyObject) {
 //call to above button action in here
 actionB("" as AnyObject)
}
```